# Using WSO2 not allow to login any identity provider(Facebook or Gmail) at second time if we try to login

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to work with wso2.

I am using Facebook or Gmail identity provider to get authenticate using travelocity application.

At First time wso2 redirect to Facebook login page or Gmail login page by which i want to login.

But at second time wso2 do not redirect to Facebook or Gmail login page direct shows home.jsp page with profile information of Facebook or Gmail.

**My question is:** What should i do if i logout then try to login then  wso2 redirect us Facebook or Gmail login page.

Answer (score 0):

This basically happens when you have the previous session stored in the browser and SAML logout has not happened properly.

Have you tried the logout button in the Travelocity app? Where did you find this smaple. Better to build and take the app from here https://github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/master/modules/samples/sso/sso-agent-sample

Futhermore, we do have two more SAML samples if you want to try. You can find them here https://github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/sso-samples/saml2-sso-sample